# Request for Assistance: Retrieving Parsed Transaction Data in Rust for Solana Test Validator

Tags: web3.js, solana-cli, solana-test-validator

Currently, I am running a Solana test validator, and it's functioning perfectly. However, I am facing a challenge when it comes to retrieving transaction data in Rust.

In the "@solana/web3.js" library for JavaScript, I noticed a convenient feature named "getParsedTransaction," allowing easy access to transaction details in a parsed format. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a similar functionality in the "solana_rpc_client" Rust package.

I am reaching out for guidance on how to achieve the equivalent of "getParsedTransaction" in Rust. Any assistance or examples you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusing, but you can fetch a parsed transaction by specifying `JsonParsed` for the encoding in `get_transaction` at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/99760e519ad7ba55f7b67d155e63e7f697c223b0/rpc-client/src/rpc_client.rs#L2592 ie:

```
let tx = rpc_client.get_transaction(/* ... signature ... */, UiTransactionEncoding::JsonParsed);
```